# Zoom in and Out through a NSView or Magnify

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am hoping to be able to make something similar to the universal access zoom window shown below.  I have already created an NSView and using a fill operation I made a rect with a clear "see through" composite to see through my window and show the desktop.  Now I am wondering if it is possible to zoom in and out inside my view just like the picture below.  I was thinking this might be an IkImageView or something I could apply but i wasent sure how it was done.  Does anyone know how to do this or show me where I could find this in the docs? Some code would be great. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Apple's example **CIAnnotation**. In this example is magnifying image but I think You can achieve what You want. You can download sample code from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CIAnnotation/Introduction/Intro.html).

CIAnnotation app example:

[image]

References and guides which can help You with this:

[Core Image Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html)
[Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)
[NSGraphicsContext Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSGraphicsContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

NSView supports zoom through `- (void)scaleUnitSquareToSize:(NSSize)newUnitSize`

This zooms the content of the view, so to use this you would have to set the Desktop behind the mouse as view content (NSImage maybe?) and then zoom the view. It will have to update when the mouse is dragged.

Check the ImageKit part of Quartz, in particular the class `IKImageView`. It has zoom features, but I have not worked with it myself yet.